# Proving $\forall x \forall y Rxy \therefore \forall x \forall y Ryx$.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

I have been having a hard time trying to understand how to prove the following proof:

$\forall x \forall y Rxy \therefore \forall x \forall y Ryx$

What I have done so far is opened the 2 sub-proofs for the Universal Introduction of $x$ and $y$ and after the subproof of $y$ assume the negation of $Rxy$ and prove that a contradiction exist, however, that where I get stuck.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include which axioms you are working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I have done so far is opened the 2 sub-proofs for the Universal Introduction of x and y...

What you hav to do is :

1) $∀x∀yRxy$

2) $∀yRay$ --- by [UI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation)

3) $Rab$ --- by UI

4) $∀yRyb$ --- by [UG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization)

> 5) $∀x∀yRyx$ --- by UG.

Comment: Really...wow thank you so much